# how can I compile a modification on the file _criterion.pyx under the sklearn library of python

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am searching to validate my idea on the decision tree algorithm. That is why I have installed **Anaconda3** and try to understand where I should modify (I am a beginner user of python language). I have understood that modification should be on the file **_criterion.pyx** under **site-packages/sklearn/tree**. Infact, under this path there is only **_criterion.pyd** which is already the compiled file of **_criterion.pyx**.

My question is how to recompile the .pyx file and how to use the configuration file (**setup.py**) in order to take into account the added modifications when using the DecisionTreeClassifier class.

Comment: I don't see a problem doing the setup.py-based install after doing changes. Of course i highly recommend doing sklearn's setup like that from the beginning. No anaconda binaries! [Some words in the docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/advanced_installation.html#linux). If you are on windows, things might be more hard.

Comment: So to be clear on what i am proposing: do not ever touch the site-packages dir (probably overwritten at next install). Keep your sklearn sources somewhere, modify, install using setup.py. This boils down on being able to install sklearn from sources.

Comment: What is wrong with Anaconda. I don't understand.. In fact, I make changes under this package in order to take into account these changes when I use the class DecisionTreeClassifier

Comment: If you change sklearn, you will have to use their build-tools to create a new install. That's what every dev is doing in one way or another (e.g. the setup.py approach). It's much more safe to do the complete install-route than trying to manually recompile things. Of course it feels more safe if there is no anaconda-based sklearn already (best-case: overwritten; worst-case: well...) Manually recompiling things, when anaconda-sklearn is there also needs to reflect anaconda's builds or there will be very bad things happening (compile-opts). So: read intros to conda vs. pip; sklearn-dev setup.

Comment: What is the nature of your proposed change? Is it something you want to contribute?

Comment: The change concerns a new definition of an entropy measure which is used on the decision tree learning algorithm